# How do I edit the .htaccess file to point to a relative directory for a 404 error document?

Tags: http, .htaccess

Most htaccess 404 error rules are based on an absolute directory location, eg /404.php.  I want one that is relative to the location it's placed in (so when I transfer from test environment in WAMP to live, I don't have to hope I edit the file right).

Unfortunately,

```
ErrorDocument 404 404Error.php
```

Just prints out 404Error.php to the browser, it doesn't call the actual error page like

```
ErrorDocument 404 /FOOBAR/404Error.php
```

does.

Edit:

I guess I wasn't clear enough.  Test environment is a WAMP local server, with the error file at /FOOBAR/404Error.php while the 'live' server would be www.fubar.com/404error.php -- placing it in the root.

Comment: Instead of having all this mess and problems with accessing your website via sub-directory (e.g. `localhost/foobar/index.php`) and domain name there, why don't you setup each site on your local WAMP as individual entry which will have unique domain name. You can easily fake domain name by adding 1 line to your `hosts` file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`). Create a domain name like `foobar.dev`, create new site in WAMP pointing the website root to that `.../foobar/` folder and access it via `http://foobar.dev/index.php`.

Comment: Such `hosts` entry will look like `127.0.0.1 foobar.dev`

Comment: If you make that a solution, I'd accept it -- it doesn't answer what I literally asked, but it does solve the problem.  There are a few details I'm not sure on (setting the WAMP to create the website root?  Woudln't that eliminate the ability to have OTHER sites on the WAMP?) but it looks like a very good solution.

Comment: You can configure each of your sites to have unique root folder and domain name (`siteA.com => C:\websites\siteA.com`, `my-site.com => C:\websites\my-site.com` etc). This is the best way if you do not want to have any quirks when this works locally but does not work on real/deployed site (or other way around). In this way you will have much similar setup locally compared to remote. This is also more beneficial if you need to take care about security aspect or some advanced Apache configuration. I have never used WAMP myself but there should be no problem at all with doing this setup.

Comment: Since this does not answer your question directly (as you've noticed yourself) I don't see much point of converting my comment into an answer (I'm not after points THAT much ;) ). In contrast -- it will be more logical for you to post an answer with your final decision/the path you decided to go. There you may thank me -- I will appreciate this :)

Answer (score 3):

How's this?

```
ErrorDocument 404 ../directory/404page.html
```

Comment: Alas, doesn't work.  I've edited my original question, but the problem is that the file will be moving FROM a non-root directory, TO a root directory.

Comment: I'm sorry if I still don't understand what you're asking, but couldn't you put "ErrorDocument 404 404page.html" in the root directory where your homepage file is (www.foobar.com/index.php)? Then every subdirectory will refer to that original .htaccess file to show the 404.

Comment: Because for some reason that isn't accepted.  It outputs '404page.html' instead of outputting the file.

Comment: Not to make you sound stupid, but did you check to see if your 404page.html page contains the text "404page.html"?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteBase /FOOBAR/
ErrorDocument 404 404Error.php
```

This works too, but Tycho's solution is a bit more elegant. Only use this one if you don't plan on using .htaccess for anything outside of `/FOOBAR/` pretty much.

Comment: As above, thanks for the effort (and +1), but doesn't work because I'm going to a root directory situation from a non-root directory.